# Git log get real commit author

Tags: git, git-log

I'm working on a git log cmd but I have trouble when I try to get the author of a commit  it didn't show me the author of the commit but the people who merged this branch.
I didn't saw how can I get the author of the branch...

This is my actual command:

```
git log -m --first-parent --date=format:%c --pretty=format:'<tr><td>%ad</td><td>%cN</td></tr>\r\n'
```

Update:

I tried with:

```
I try with ` git log --date=format:%c --pretty=format:'<tr><td>%ad</td><td>%cN</td></tr>\r\n'`, i still get the same result
```

And I still get the same result

Comment: Check this: Find out a Git branch creator https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12055198/find-out-a-git-branch-creator and may  filter the merges https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35945860/view-git-log-without-merge-commits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find ! I have to use `aN` instead of `cN`, `a` is for author and `c` for comitter

Answer (score 0):

From the `git log` [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log):

> **--first-parent**
>
> Follow only the first parent commit upon seeing a merge commit. This option can give a better overview when viewing the evolution of a particular topic branch, because merges into a topic branch tend to be only about adjusting to updated upstream from time to time, and this option allows you to ignore the individual commits brought in to your history by such a merge. Cannot be combined with --bisect.

If you set this option, then you will get only the names of people that were merging the branch.

I suggest you to exclude this option from your command.

Comment: I try with ` git log --date=format:%c --pretty=format:'<tr><td>%ad</td><td>%cN</td></tr>\r\n'`, i still get the same result