# Why does GitHub add all commits from the feature branch to main when doing a merge commit?

Tags: git, github, git-merge

From my understanding, a [`git merge`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) from a feature branch to the main branch creates a new commit on main that has two ancestors (the last commit on the feature branch and the last commit on main). Only one commit that merges the changes from both branches (the merge commit) will be added to main. Am I correct here?

Opposed to that, when I merge a Pull Request an GitHub with the option "Create a merge commit", **all** commits from the feature breanch are being added on top of the main branch and then of top of that there is the expected merge commit. Adding all commits to main is a behavior I would expect form rebase, but I'm under the impression that I'm doing a merge commit here (which is backed by the fact that an additional merge commit is being created).

The [GitHub docs](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/configuring-pull-request-merges/about-merge-methods-on-github) are very ambiguous about the different PR merge methods. For the default merge option "Create a merge commit" it says:

> [...] all commits from the feature branch are added to the base branch in a merge commit. The pull request is merged using the --no-ff option.

Which sounds very much like what it does but not like what I would expect from a git merge.

It sounds even more so, if I compare it to what the docs say about "Squash and merge":

> When you select the Squash and merge option on a pull request on GitHub.com, the pull request's commits are squashed into a single commit.

I could do "Squash and Merge" instead of just merging, but the docs also warn about re-using already merged branches:

> If you continue working on the head branch of a pull request after squashing and merging, and then create a new pull request between the same branches, commits that you previously squashed and merged will be listed in the new pull request.

Re-using merged branches is something I would occasionally do, so I'd prefer to go with the normal merge.

So what are my options to get expected git merge behavior on GitHub? Or do I understand something wrong here?

---

EDIT: @Gaël J's comment gave me the idea that GitHub still has this graphical branch view somewhere hidden in the repository's insights and according to this view, the merge commits are being done as I would expect:

[image]

But when I go into the Code view and look into the history of main, I see all those commits as if they would have been done on main. Might be another "improvement" of GitHub to adhere to some new dev style, but I find it very confusing. I also did not find any option to turn that behavior off and only see the actual commits on main if main is selected :-(

Comment: It depends, if you usually do 150 commits for two weeks per big feature, it is better to squash them, it preserves a clean history. If branches are not diverged since creation of `feature` branch, merge will be fast-forward - it also preserves a more clean history. So, if i were you, i would use compromise - use default github behavior, but squash commits manually, for example with `git reset --soft`. This way you use all of the tools for history to be clean and can reuse your branches. You can repeat squashes, but don't squash those commits that was result of previous squash.

Comment: The GitHub docs state that a merge commit is always done with the `--no-ff` option. And I remember that some months ago merging a PR just created a merge commit and nothing else. So something seems to have changed under the hood ...

Comment: If people refer to "clean history", what does this actually mean? For me, a clean history on main is to have one merge commit for each feature and nothing else. Are we on the same page here?

Comment: It's okay, it is just for preserving history - others will see there were a merge here.  For rebase, for example for commits `A - B`, with B being rebased to A, it is possible that B was created earlier than A but follows after A in history. Complete hiding of what truly happened.

Comment: By clean history usually implied that commits are logically independent, and don't have commits kinda with name `bugfix of <some>` but actually contained some versions bump up, and some refactoring, etc.., completely disentangled and independent commits. There is a kind of release, based on it, called `semantic release`, where you give to commits specific names for selective releases.

Comment: I think you're confusing what the GitHub UI is showing (a list of commits, without any branching paths) with the visual representation you expect (branch paths). Maybe open the repo in a GUI tool like gitg/gitk/whatever tool with a "graph view" to see what you expect?

Comment: @Fred, answering to your question about "clean history" - generally it is a couple of points afaik 1) the less functional commits - the better (for big features, but bigger size commits), 2) the less non-functional commits - the better (about merge commits)

Comment: @GaëlJ: I expect GitHub to show only commits on main if main is the selected branch. I don't want to have some kind of Guitar Hero view, but I also don't want to have stuff from different branches mixed together in what seems to be the view on one branch...

Comment: @GaëlJ you gave me an idea, I edited my post with more insights. Does this clarify the problem?

Comment: That's not a "problem", that's a product choice which actually make sense. You can possibly get the view you'd like from git CLI: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8527139/showing-commits-made-directly-to-a-branch-ignoring-merges-in-git

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, **the behaviour you expect with merge commits is what is really happening**.

This can be verified in the "graphical view".

**You're being confused by the "commits list" view** which shows all commits belonging to a branch without the branching paths.

Why does GitHub display like this? Because that's still the reality. A branch is just a pointer to a commit.  All ancestors commits are part of the branch, no matter if at the time they've been pushed they were pushed to another branch name.

A commit belongs to a branch if it's reachable from the "head commit" of the branch (the pointer).

---

Edit: with Git directly, you can possibly get the view you'd like. See [Showing commits made directly to a branch, ignoring merges in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8527139/showing-commits-made-directly-to-a-branch-ignoring-merges-in-git)

Answer (score 2):

> From my understanding, a `git merge` from a feature branch to the main branch creates a new commit on main *that has two ancestors* (the last commit on the feature branch and the last commit on main). Only one commit that merges the changes from both branches (the merge commit) will be added to main. Am I correct here? (emphasis mine)

No, not quite. A merge commit has two (or more) parents, that's absolutely correct. But commits are not "added to a branch". Commits always point to their direct parent(s). A branch is a reference (a "ref" in Git jargon) that points to an arbitrary commit. Branch refs can be moved freely and Git mostly helps you with that: whenever you `git commit` and currently have a branch checked out, the current branch ref is moved to the new commit.

So which commits are part of a branch? Obviously. the commit which is referenced by the branch ref. And its parent or parents commits. And their parent commits. And so on.

Consequently, if you have a merge commit, both sides of the merge are part of the branch.

---

GitHub shows a flat list of the history, which is not accurate. Use a proper tool to visualize history, such as the default `gitk` or `git log --oneline --decorate --graph`. They will show the relation between commits and will display the two sides of a merge as separate "lines".

If you are only interested in one side of the merge, you can use the `--first-parent` option to only show the *left* side of the merges, i.e. exclude the commits that were previously only reachable from your feature branches.

---

A picture is worth a thousand words, here's a small ASCII graphic of a history including merge commits; before and after the merge:

```
F     <- feature
E
D
| C   <- main
\ B 
  A
```

Commits B, C are only *reachable* from `main`, commits D, E, F are only reachable from `feature`, and commit A is reachable from both branches.

Merging creates a new merge commit:

```
M     <- main
|\
| F   <- feature
| E
| D
C |
B /
A
```

It's easy to see that all commits (A, B, C, D, E, F, and M) are *reachable* from branch `main` ("on branch main", "part of branch main", "in branch main"; whatever you want to call it. Commits D, E, F, and A are additionally reachable through branch feature.

Comment: "GitHub shows a flat list of the history, which is not accurate." My confusion came from the fact that it did indeed show the history correctly until a couple of weeks ago and now does not anymore :-|

Answer (score 1):

"Adding a commit to a branch" is a simplification. You don't really add a commit to a branch but you are first creating the commit and then updating the branch to point to the commit because a branch is *just a reference to a commit*.

GitHub isn't doing anything different from that except using `--no-ff` to disable fast-forward merges in case there are no new commits on the branch you merge into. In this case, GitHub (or git with `--no-ff`) will still create a merge commit.

Assume you have a history like this:

```
A-->B-->C<-- master
 \->D-->E<-- feature
```

#### Merge commit

If you then merge `feature` into `master`, you will get the following history:

```
A-->B-->C-->M<-- master
 \->D-->E--/
        ^-- feature
```

It created a new commit (M) with 2 parents and master points to the new merge commit. None of the parent commits of `M` are preferred.

It will create a single new commit but the branch will have all commits from both parents.

#### Squash and merge

If you instead squash it, it will look as follows:

```
A-->B-->C-->DE<-- master
            ^-- feature
```

where `DE` is a new commit containing both the changes of `D` and `E`.

However, as stated in the docs, if you have other work based on that feature branch, it will cause problems as you have the same changes under different branches. If you have

```
A-->B-->C<-- master
 \->D-->E<-- feature
     \->F<-- other
```

and you squash and merge `feature` into `master`, you will have the following scenario:

```
A-->B-->C-->DE<-- master
 \          ^-- feature
  \->D-->F<-- other
```

So, you might not want to use the `squash and merge` option if you have work based on the feature branch you are squashing.

##### fixing it with `cherry-pick`

If you still want to do that, you could "fix" these branches by cherry-picking. Cherry-picking means you are applying all changes from a commit as a new commit somewhere else.

In this case, you can add a temporary branch based on the master branch and add each of the new commits from the other branch to that and then update the feature branch:

```
A-->B-->C-->DE<-- master
 \          ^-- feature
  \->D-->F<-- other
```

`git checkout -b tmp master`

```
A-->B-->C-->DE<-- master
 \          ^-- tmp
  \->D-->F<-- other
```

`git cherry-pick F`

```
A-->B-->C-->DE<-- master
 \          \->F'<-- tmp
  \->D-->F<-- other
```

Then, you update `other` to point to `tmp` instead (`git checkout other` and `git reset --hard tmp` **make sure you know what you are doing** before using commands like that):

```
A-->B-->C-->DE<-- master
            \->F'<-- other
```

Whether you actually want to do this approach is up to you. Personally, I would recommend just merging with a merge commit so you don't have to deal with problems in other work based on feature branches. Alternatively, you can make sure that all work based on the feature branch is integrated into the feature branch (however you like to do that) before merging the feature branch into master.

Comment: You just parroted the git docs. I understand what they are saying. But GitHub is doing something different.

Comment: GitHub is doing the same what git is doing (except that it doesn't do fast-forward merges). It might just _show_ you something else in the web UI. GitHub is doing what I described here just as git is doing that. What exactly does it show you differently?

Comment: @Fred it is up to you to decide, don't want fast-forward - use `create merge commit` option, history is preserved, BUT *non-functional* merge commit is created - so, history is a bit dirty. Fast-forwards enable not doing merge commits, if possible. That said, add here manual squashing for the best approach.

Comment: My problem is: I do want exactly that behavior (because the merge commits are the history I need to track new features, so they are way more useful than all the nitty gritty commits I do on my feature branch). But GitHub is not just adding a merge commit to main, but _all_ commits from the feature branch and on top of that a merge commit. That behavior is weird and I don't know how to get back to "just a merge commit and nothing else".

Comment: I suspected that this is just a matter of how GitHub shows me the history as well, and not what is actually going on in the repo, but I couldn't find any option to turn this behavior off

Comment: As I wrote in my first commit, GitHub isn't adding any commit to a branch. It is setting the branch reference to the merge commit which results in all commits being in the history. This is what git does as well. If a commit is in the history of a branch, its parents are part of the history as well. If you want a single commit per merge, use squashing. Also, if you want a view on the actual commit history, clone the repository and view it with a tool displaying you the history as a graph.

Comment: @Fred merge commit - is non functional (unless there were conflicts), ie anyway you will see those commits created in feature branch. You can check it out via `git show` command. It will not show you any changes.

Comment: :-D okay, I understand now why people are opposing merge commits. From a technical POV you're right. But for me those commits are the only truly long-term useful commits because they contain the changelog of a feature that was merged and I use them to track the history of my product on a more abstract level. The commits on the feature branch are only useful until I have merged the feature.

Comment: If you want to, you could also filter the commits locally and just display the merge commits between two commits.

Comment: "GitHub isn't adding any commit to a branch" But why offer the concept of branches then if it doesn't behave accordingly? IMHO "add to a branch" is the synonym to "put a direct link to what's currently considered HEAD of a branch into the commit, then make that commit HEAD of that branch". But what it acutally does is "only link to the HEAD of the feature branch, the make it HEAD of the main branch". That doesn't make sense to me. Why are we even using the concept of branches then?

Comment: The idea of a branch is that you have some top-level reference to a commit and usually only update it in a way that all commits in the history of the branch stay in the history (not force push to long-lived branches) normally.